# Not able to access method of another activity class

Tags: android, methods

I am getting the null pointer exception error at this line `Log.d("Density",obj.getDensity());`
here is the whole code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AndroidUtil obj = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("Phone Model",AndroidUtil.PHONE_MODEL);
    Log.d("API Level","::"+AndroidUtil.APILEVEL);
    Log.d("Android Version",AndroidUtil.VERSION);
    Log.d("Code Name",AndroidUtil.CODE_NAME);
    Log.d("BootLoader",AndroidUtil.BOOT_LOADER);
    Log.d("Board",AndroidUtil.BOARD);
    Log.d("Brand",AndroidUtil.BRAND);
    Log.d("Manufacturer",AndroidUtil.MANUFACTURER);
    Log.d("Hardware",AndroidUtil.HARDWARE);
    //Log.d("Pixel Width","::"+obj.getWidthInPx());
    //Log.d("Pixel Height","::"+obj.getHeightInPx());
    //Log.d("Dp Width","::"+obj.getWidthInDp());
    //Log.d("Dp Height","::"+obj.getHeightInDp());
    Log.d("Density",obj.getDensity());
}
```

}

Now my AndroidUtil class is here

```
public class AndroidUtil extends Activity {
    int Measuredwidth = 0;  
    int Measuredheight = 0;  
    Point size = new Point();

    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    static final int APILEVEL = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    static final String PHONE_MODEL = android.os.Build.MODEL;

    static final String BOOT_LOADER = android.os.Build.BOOTLOADER;

    static final String BOARD = android.os.Build.BOARD;

    static final String VERSION = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    static final String CODE_NAME = android.os.Build.VERSION.CODENAME;

    static final String BRAND = android.os.Build.BRAND;

    static final String MANUFACTURER = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

    static final String HARDWARE = android.os.Build.HARDWARE;   

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int getHeightInPx(){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
              w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
              Measuredheight = size.y; 
         }else{
              Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
              Measuredheight = d.getHeight(); 
        }
        return Measuredheight;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int getWidthInPx(){
        Log.d("Width","called");
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
              w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
              Measuredwidth = size.x; 
         }else{
              Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
              Measuredwidth = d.getWidth(); 
        }
        return Measuredwidth;
    }

    public float getHeightInDp(){
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

        float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
        return dpHeight;
    }

    public float getWidthInDp(){
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

        float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
        return dpWidth;
    }

    public String getDensity(){
        Log.d("density","called");
        String DPI = null;
        switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            DPI = "Low Density";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            DPI = "Medium Density";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            DPI = "High Density";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            DPI = "Extra High Density";
            break;
        }
        return DPI;
    }
}
```

Log cat error :

```
    04-03 17:51:57.799: E/filePathInTheme(5781): fallback to res
04-03 17:51:57.829: E/filePathInTheme(5781): fallback to res
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Phone Model(5781): A100
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/API Level(5781): ::15
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Android Version(5781): 4.0.4
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Code Name(5781): REL
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/BootLoader(5781): unknown
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Board(5781): 7x27
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Brand(5781): China Telecom
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Manufacturer(5781): Micromax
04-03 17:51:57.859: D/Hardware(5781): qcom
04-03 17:51:57.869: W/dalvikvm(5781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a839d8)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andutil/com.andutil.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4450)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at com.andutil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
04-03 17:51:57.869: E/AndroidRuntime(5781):     ... 11 more
```

Please help !!!

Comment: your activity is null `AndroidUtil obj = null;`, how do you expect to get it work? And actually what you want to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: you are not initialize AndroidUtil obj.

Comment: hey I have changed that to obj = new AndroidUtil()

Comment: @CautionContinues Dont instantiate Activity class

Comment: Just explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: problem is I am not able to execute methods of AndroidUtil class

Comment: I am making an util file so that whenever in any app if we need to consider the density, height, width or any other factor...

Comment: In my opinion it's better to create another class which is not an Activity, give a param Context of your current activity and access your methods using that class.

Comment: okies let me try @ Android-Developer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good option to initialise Activities like this (and I'm pretty sure it won't work in any kind of situations, it's context will be always null). To achieve the things you want to do in my opinion the best way is create an AndroidUtils class like this :

```
public class AndroidUtils {

     private Context mContext;

     public AndroidUtils(Context context){
          this.mContext = context;
     }

}
```

and everywhere you need a context variable in your `getDensity()` and etc. use `mContext`.
After doing that you can use this class from any Activity like this :

```
AndroidUtils mObject = new AndroidUtils(MainActivity.this);
mObject.getDensity();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an activity which is null and thus not initialized.

```
AndroidUtil obj = null;
...
Log.d("Density",obj.getDensity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did assign `null` to `obj`:

```
AndroidUtil obj = null;
```

If you want an `Activity` instance in there, you have to do some pretty dirty hacks. Instead of saving a reference to `AndroidUtil` and calling methods on it, you should use `Intents` to communicate your `Activities`.

1. You can use `startActivityForResult`, or
2. You can launch the `Activity` with a regular `Intent`, then have it register itself on a global object.

Looking at what your code does, these are both bad ideas. I would just move the code for `AndroidUtil` into your main `Activity`.

If you want to keep the code out of the main `Activity`, implement it as static helpers that take an `Activity` as parameter, instead of sublcassing `Activity` to access its facilities.

Comment: create another class which is not an Activity

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you declared the object null? ==> `AndroidUtil obj = null;`

Answer (score 0):

just add these code

```
 String print = AndroidUtil.class.getDensity();

 Log.d("Density",print);
```

Comment: class `Class<?>` has no method called `getDensity()`